# Localhost : requested URL not found

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, deployment, localhost

I am trying to deploy a web app developped with spring mvc, hibernate and MySQL, I am trying to deploy it to tomcat 8. I copied the war file (bureau.war) of the app in the folder webapps when the tomcat started, the folder "bureau" is created, but, once i try to connect to the app URL : http://localhost/bureau/index, I get this error : The requested URL /bureau/index was not found on this server.

It's been 3 days, I am looking for a solution to this

This is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/WEB-INF/views/relogin.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is servlet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>


<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.commune.bureau" />



</beans:beans>
```

When Tomcat is starting I get the following errors :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Xz4.png)

Comment: Please provide your web.xml and your spring servlet definition (xml or java). Any log trace would be helpfull to

Comment: I provided web.xml and servlet-context.xml, please check my edited post @jlumietu

Comment: Ok, check tomcat's server.xml to see if 80 is actually the port assigned in the http connector. If is ok, then check if you can reach one static element from within `resources` folder of your project. Check also if the `base-package` is the correct root package of your controllers. If so, ensure the controllers are annotated with correct `@Controller` of `@RestController`. If none of the above seem suspicious, please include server logs.

Comment: I changed tomcat version to tomcat 8.5 and know i amgetting error 404, I can connect to url : localhost, I edited my post to add some errors i am getting when tomcat is starting